# assertHeader in Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase not working?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I started to write some unit test for an app in zend framework.
Looking around I came to the PHPunit and then to the Zend_Test (which in turn extends the PHPunit).

So I opted to write tests with Zend_Test since it gives me some zend framework specific assertions...

All went fine until I had to check in a test the response headers...
My intuition was to use the `$this->assertHeader($headerNameToCheckIfItExists)` assertion. Unfortunately it **failed**.
So I started to look around why it fails... I checked that my application sets the header in the response (and it sets it correctly) and after that I checked with `curl` the raw response Http headers. It appears that the setted header by the application is present in the response!

*So what is the problem?*

The problem is that in zend application the headers can be set with `$this->setHeader($headerName, $headerValue)` method as well as with `$this->setRawHeader($headerNameAndHeaderValue)` method. There is also the `$this->getHeaders()` and the `$this->getRawHeaders()` to get the headers as an array of key value pair or as an array of plain string, respectively. (Looking in the source code I discovered that there are 2 distinct arrays of headers - one with key value elements and other with plain string elements)

In my app I used the `$this->setRawHeader($headerNameAndHeaderValue)` and the `$this->assertHeader($headerNameToCheckIfItExists)` fails. If I use `$this->setHeader($headerName, $headerValue)` the `$this->assertHeader($headerNameToCheckIfItExists)` does not fail...

So it appears that the `$this->assertHeader($headerNameToCheckIfItExists)` checks if the `$headerNameToCheckIfItExists` header name exists by looking only in the `$this->getResponse()->getHeaders()`!

Please, if some one knows something about this "drawback" answer at this post.

The workaround I made is to overload the `$this->assertHeader($headerNameToCheckIfItExists)` in my test case file:

```
public function assertHeader($header, $message='') {
    $all_headers = array();
    foreach ($this->getResponse()->getRawHeaders() as $str) {
        $components = explode(":", $str);
        $all_headers[] = array('name' => $components[0],
                'value' => trim($components[1]),
                'replace' => false);
    }
    $all_headers = array_merge($all_headers, $this->getResponse()->getHeaders());

    foreach ($all_headers as $h) 
        if ($h['name'] == $header)
            return $this->assertTrue(true, $message);

    $this->fail('no header with name: '.$header);    
}
```

My zend framework version:

```
zf show version
Zend Framework Version: 1.10.6
```